# Cross correlation of different time series in a matrix

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

Looking for a solution to my problem I found an old post ([Cross correlation of different time series data values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537687/cross-correlation-of-different-time-series-data-values-in-r)) which asks exactly for what I need but unfortunately It didnt get any answer so I will ask again hoping for some guidance.

I have created a big matrix from a big number of time series with the same size, each column is a different time serie (something similar to the following but much bigger and much more values different than zero):

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA    NA    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[2,]    0   6.0   0.0   9.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[3,]    0   0.0   0.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[4,]    0   0.0   0.0  10.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[5,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[6,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[7,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[8,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA   0.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
[9,]    0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    NA     0    NA  10.0    NA   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
.
.
.
```

I want to determine the correlation between all the time series, I put them in a matrix because I thought it could be the best way to do a cross-correlation procedure, I might be wrong.

So, I also know about the functions "ccf" and "diss()":

1. ccf() #in base packages
2. diss(meter_daywise,METHOD = "CORT",deltamethod = "DTW")#in TSclust package

but like in the old post, I have the same issues:

1. ccf do not take full matrix as input
2. diss() takes input matrix and produces some matrix, but while observing the values I find that it is not a cross-correlation matrix because the values are not between -1 and 1.

So the question is how do we compute and perform cross-correlation between different time-series in R?

Comment: What do you expect the output look like?

Comment: I was hoping to create as a result a matrix of dimension AxA where A=number of time series, and every value in this matrix with coordinates [x,y] is the correlation between the time series (x) and the time series (y). Is this possible and does make sense?

Comment: It sounds like you might just want a plain old correlation matrix. For your structure, this would be `cor(myMat)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ccf` returns the pairwise correlation at each offset (i.e. lag) but I think what you want is the max(abs(correlation) from that. Because you have NA's you need to set the `na.action` argument.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol=100)
mat[sample(1:length(mat), 100)] <- NA 

res <- sapply(1:ncol(mat), function(x) {
  sapply(1:ncol(mat), function(z){
    resTmp <- ccf(x = mat[, x], y = mat[, z], plot=F, na.action = na.pass)
    resTmp$acf[which.max(abs(resTmp$acf))]
  })
})
```

From the `ccf` help:

> By default, no missing values are allowed. If the na.action function passes through missing values (as na.pass does), the covariances are computed from the complete cases. This means that the estimate computed may well not be a valid autocorrelation sequence, and may contain missing values.

Comment: thanks, but I cannot make it work, should I use the code except the first 2 lines and using my matrix (matri123) instead of the matrix  mat of this example? I tried like that and doesn work, could you give me a hand?   An addtional question would be why is it better to apply absolute maximum correlation?

Comment: 1) Yes, use your matrix in place of `mat`. You will need to elaborate on why/how it is not working. Error messages wrong results? 2) It is not necessarily better to use abs max correlation, that was an educated guess on my part. ccf returns a vector of correlation per pair of time-series and because you wanted an AxA matrix we have to reduce each pairwise correlation to one value, in this case that would seem to be the maximum correlation (disregarding the sign). If you elaborate on your use case we can come up with something else.

Comment: I am getting a matrix of AxA as a results with what seems to be the correlations of every pair, which pretty much what I was looking for. I have 2 final questions and I am sorry I dont know much about the topic,  1.Many of the elements in the resulting matrix are: Numeric,0    do you know why this happens and how can I avoid it?   2.Is there a way to obtain a correlation value not for a pair of time series but for a time series with a group of them (ex: time serie A correlation with the group of time series "A,B,C,D,E")? I appreciate very much any guidance#

Comment: 1) you will need to create a reproducible example for us to troubleshoot, but I would suspect it has to do with column lots of NAs or are all 0. 2) Ye you can perform hierarchical clustering and then use the dendrogram to approximate the distance between a single time-series and a group of time-series. But you cannot do it like you would in the pair-wise scenario

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to run `ccf` across all combinations of your columns using `combn`. The following code was tested on the question in the link:

```
myResults <- combn(seq_len(nrow(meter_daywise)), 2,
                   FUN=function(x) ccf(meter_daywise[x[1],], meter_daywise[x[2],]),
                   simplify=FALSE)
```

and produces a nested list like this

```
str(myResults)
List of 10
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ acf   : num [1:17, 1, 1] 0.0241 0.0895 0.1463 0.0583 -0.0613 ...
  ..$ type  : chr "correlation"
  ..$ n.used: int 15
  ..$ lag   : num [1:17, 1, 1] -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 ...
  ..$ series: chr "X"
  ..$ snames: chr "meter_daywise[x[1], ] & meter_daywise[x[2], ]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "acf"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ acf   : num [1:17, 1, 1] -0.445 -0.493 -0.239 0.465 0.49 ...
  ..$ type  : chr "correlation"
  ..$ n.used: int 15
  ..$ lag   : num [1:17, 1, 1] -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 ...
  ..$ series: chr "X"
  ..$ snames: chr "meter_daywise[x[1], ] & meter_daywise[x[2], ]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "acf"

...
```

Each outer element in the list is the output of a `ccf` for two pairs. For your application, as the time series are stored in the columns, you switch this to

```
myResults <- combn(seq_len(ncol(myMat)), 2,
                   FUN=function(x) ccf(myMat[, x[1]], myMat[, x[2]]), simplify=FALSE)
```

where myMat is the name of your matrix. You can see the pairs with a simpler call to `combn` like

```
myPairs <- combn(seq_len(ncol(myMat)), 2)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I cannot make it work. My matrix(matts) has dimensions 25 columns x 13514 rows, I tried with your command:    myResults <- combn(seq_len(ncol(matts)), 2, FUN=function(x) ccf(matts[, x[1]], matts[, x[2]]), simplify=FALSE)      and I am getting the error:  Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object         So I thougth it might be due the NA values so ireplace them for other values only to test if it works and then I get the error:     Error in plot.window(...) : final 'ylim' values necessary      Im really lost here. what can I do?